# Jitters in time difference between c++ chronos and Bluetooth `hcitool clock`

Tags: c++, bluetooth

## What I am trying to

I want to calculate an offset between a system clock and Bluetooth device's internal clock and to see if the offset is constant or not (theoretically, it should be constant).

## Primer

Bluetooth device's internal clock is ticking 3200 times per second (i.e., 312.5 us/tick). It can be retrieved by executing a command `hcitool clock`. Here is demo:

[image]

## What I've done

1. I made a program that iterates 100 times that:

   1. Gets a system clock value in microseconds via `std::chronos::high_resolution_clock::now()`
   2. Gets Bluetooth device's internal clock via `hcitool clock`.
   3. Prints out both values (with comma separated).
2. I copied and pasted the printed result and calculates `system_clock - BT_clock * 312.5` and plotted it.

Raw data is in [here (GitHub Gist)](https://gist.github.com/gsongsong/a80e0f179ecc9cbb6f43f22bf419d091)

## Observation

I expected that an offset of each trial should be (nearly) zero. However, in reality, it shows a certain steady value with jitters. Belows are plots of individual value and probability density function.

[image]

[image]

## Problem

So, how can I remove jitters effectively? I guess a couple of reasons:

- `high_resolution_clock::now()` and `hcitool clock` are not executed simultaneously. So there might be a random jitter (may include context switching)
- Both the function and opening a process inside a program are expensive to call
- USB-type Bluetooth dongle cannot guarantee that `hcitool clock` returns a result within a guaranteed time limit.

However, I have no confidence which is true and which is not and have no idea how can I solve the problem if each guess is true.

## Source code

```
/* g++ soruce-code.cc -std=c++11*/
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main() {
    #define BUFLEN 128
    #define CLKLEN 10 
    char buf[BUFLEN], clock_char[CLKLEN];
    unsigned long clock_long;
    FILE* pipe;
    auto t = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto us = time_point_cast<microseconds>(t).time_since_epoch().count();
    cout << "system,bt" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i != 100; i++) {
        t = high_resolution_clock::now();
        us = time_point_cast<microseconds>(t).time_since_epoch().count();

        pipe = popen("hcitool clock", "r");
        if (!pipe) {
            cout << "command hcitool clock failed" << endl;
            pclose(pipe);
            break;
        }
        while (!feof(pipe)) {
            if (fgets(buf, BUFLEN, pipe) == NULL) break;
            if (strncmp(buf, "Clock", 5)) break;
            strncpy(clock_char, buf + 10, CLKLEN);
            clock_char[CLKLEN] = 0;
            clock_long = stoul(clock_char, nullptr, 16);
            cout << us << "," << clock_long << endl;
            break;
        }
        pclose(pipe);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"theoretically, it should be constant"_ Why?

Comment: Because both clock expressed in microseconds are ticking with the same speed. Except that BT clock is quantized by 312.5 us

Comment: Different clocks have different stabilities though, no?

Comment: I think that' a problem in real world, not in theory. I posted it because of that reality problem, to reduce/minimize its effect.

Comment: And I think my question is still valid even though they use different clocks because the difference does not diverge and shapes Gaussian-like distribution.

Comment: Yep, I don't dispute that :)